# NGRX and Nested Relationships Example

Tags: angular, angular6, ngrx

Does anyone have a example of using NGRX with related/nested data that is more than 1 level deep? It seems there is only simple examples of using ngrx and I have yet to see a real world example?

I currently have taken ngrx out of my project since it seems it is taking to long to try to figure out on an advanced level with lack of documentation or example of more than 1 table, I've tried using entities but has slowed development and still have no clue how to use related entities. 1 level no problem but multiple levels seems this may over complicate things.

I would like to see a sample with multiple tables and relationships. Also seems I have replaced forkJoin with dispatching multiple actions? Is there a way to dispatch multiple actions as 1 action such as load tasks, load users, load contracts?

My structure looks as such:

```
Task
-TaskId
-Title
-AssignedToUser (User)
-Attachments (Array of Attachments)
-Comments (Array of Comments)
-Reviewers (Array of Users)
-Approvers (Array of Users)

Comment
-CommentId
-CommentText
-User (User)


User 
-UserId
-Name
-Contracts (Array of Contracts)
-Roles (array of Roles)


Contract
-ContractId
-ContractName

Role
-RoleId
-RoleName
```

The data from the web api is nested json so I'm not sure how to transform, create selectors for all this so if anyone has a sample that is similar that would be very helpful. I understand most of NGRX but confused how to build selectors for all this.

Answer (score 1):

After some research and more digging around I think I'm looking more for a library like **Normalizr**: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr and found a post on Redux that explains more about nested data:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuringreducers/normalizingstateshape

Answer (score 0):

So the first thing is you need to understand it's not a good idea to put everything into the Store. It's not your local database.

There are a few posts on the internet talking about when not to use Store, that might be helpful for giving you some insights.

And secondly, the State structure should be as plain as possible, otherwise, you'll soon go into trouble dealing with mutation issues as I'm sure you know the State should be immutable. If you nest the State too many levels, every time you want to change a tiny piece in the deepest level it's going to be a pain.

Lastly, I shared one piece of the State structure from the project I'm recently working on. Not so much helpful for you but just want to show how a real project state might look like.

[image]

Comment: I have components that bind to all the above though so I don't get why I would use it then? This is a huge project so that is just a few objects in the actual application OI have the basics of it working but if I have related data and it's not good to nest then there's not really a reason to use it I guess. Is NGRX for simple projects only?

Comment: I actually was only trying it out on one feature but I'm not sold on it yet beside maybe UI state

Comment: _Is NGRX for simple projects only_ I think it's the other way around. It suits better for complex projects. I too was struggling about whether or not I should introduce ngrx to my project as it's a commercial big project and a group of frontend people are working on it. But I'm happy I made the decision and so far it works perfectly fine. And I really enjoy the flexibility of it.

Comment: It seems it's lacking documentation and there's a limitation to using it with nesting entities I guess? I would like to see an example project with related entities? I can actually be finished developing this feature before I can find an example project that is more than one layer deep. I have 4 entities and can't seem to find any documentation of how relationships work

Comment: Try @ngrx/entity, that might be what you are looking for. Although I didn't use it for my project. https://medium.com/ngrx/introducing-ngrx-entity-598176456e15

Comment: Well that's what my post is talking about, I've already have and why I'm requesting a sample of using it in a real project. Thanks for trying to help but there's nothing helpful you are posting

Answer (score 0):

There is an another route

use https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter#adapter-collection-methods map function to do deep clone.

```
return adapter.map(
  entity => entity.id == obj.id ? {...entity, foo: 'bar'} : entity, 
  state
);
```

or you can use https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction to handle this

```
return adapter.map(
  entity => entity.id == obj.id ? produce(entity, (draft: any) => { draft.foo = 'bar' }) : entity, 
  state
);
```